# How to get this .php code from my theme into my plugin?

Tags: php

the original .php part of my theme looks like this:

```
$bam_related_posts_taxonomy = get_theme_mod( 'bam_related_posts_taxonomy', 'category' );


$bam_post_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => absint( get_theme_mod( 'bam_related_posts_count', '3' ) ),
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'post__not_in'      => array( get_the_ID() ),
);


(*A lot of other codes here*)


wp_reset_postdata();
```

I added this part below the 'post___not_in' myself:

```
'category__not_in'  => array(21),
```

This way, I exclude a certain category. It's working, however, I want to add this last part of the code in my own plugin, so it won't reset when I update my theme. How do I get this last line into the functions.php of my own plugin? Simply adding that line to it won't work, it needs to point to the rest of the code...

Comment: Is this a theme or a child theme? Note that the `__not_in` type parameters are extremely expensive/slow those queries are very heavy on the server

Comment: This is not a child theme. That's why I use my own plugin for .php codes

Answer (score 0):

You don't, what you've modified is a template file, those don't go in plugins.

Instead, create a child theme and copy this file into that theme. WordPress will preferentially load templates from the child theme, falling back to the original parent theme. This way any modifications you make in the child theme will overwrite the parent, and if the parent is updated no changes are lost

Comment: Mmmh but is there no way to link to it from in my plugin?

Comment: You could try to use `pre_get_posts` to filter that specific query but it would be very difficult to target just that specific query. You can't _move_ parts of a template to a plugin without making modifications to the original theme, you'd create a function in the plugin then modify the theme to call it, but that still leaves you with the original problem. **This is the whole reason child themes were invented, you're meant to use child themes to solve this problem, use a child theme**